# Как передать значение из одного активити в значение кнопки другого активити?

Tags: android, activity

В общем имеется код с Динамической генерацией кнопок, при нажатии на данную кнопку появляется форма(новая активити) и из поля (name of app) необходимо достать содержимое и установить как название кнопки.Сейчас просто стоит название "Account #...". Не могу догнать помогите пожалуйста. 
Это активити с генерацией кнопок

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_second);
        button=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                b.setText("Account №" + Integer.toString(countID + 1));
                b.setLayoutParams(
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                );
                b.setId(USERID + countID);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Form_second.this, Form_Storage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
//                        linearLayout.removeView(v);
                    }
                });
                linearLayout.addView(b);
                countID++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Это активити с вводом и сохранением данных тут по логике должно быть назначение для имени

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_storage);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_first1);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
        e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_password2);
        e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_password3);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(App)) {
            e3.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(App, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            e1.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
            e2.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));

        }



        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            String n = e1.getText().toString();
            String e = e2.getText().toString();
            String q = e3.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(App, q);
            editor.putString(Name, n);
            editor.putString(Email, e);
            editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfuly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
```

И как сделать так чтобы созданные кнопки не исчезали после перезапуска?

Comment: данные между активити передаются через интенты. SharedPreferences вам нужны, если нужно что-то сохранить и использовать после перезапуска приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи данных между Activity применяется метод putExtra(), который позволяет передать данные типов String, int, float, double, long, short, byte, char, массивы этих типов, либо объект интерфейса Serializable.
Для этого:

1. Создать Intent, как Вы и сделали

   `Intent intent = new Intent(Form_second.this, Form_Storage.class);`
2. Добавить в intent данные, которые Вы хотите передать (в виде пары ключ-значение), например, так:

   `intent.putExtra("name", "button1");`

где "name" - название extras (ключ), "button1" - значение, которое вы хотите передать.

3. Запустить Activity

   `startActivity(intent);`
4. Во втором Activity принять данные, например, так:

   `Intent intent = getIntent(); String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");`

и использовать эти данные там, где нужно.

Учитывайте, что для разных типов данных методы разные. Для строк - getStringExtra(), для целых чисел int - getIntExtra() и так далее.